# Change built-in module linux kernel

Tags: module, kernel, linux-device-driver

Apparently, modules (loadable and built-in) are stored in the

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

directory. According to different topics, you need to recompile the kernel if you want to change a built in module. I would like to know what would happen if I replaced a .ko module in the

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
```

directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: You don't need to recompile entire kernel in most cases if your kernel version is v2.6.x.y+.

Comment: @0andriy He is talking about the built in module not the loadable module. So he need to recompile the entire kernel.